# sorting a vector with custom objects

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to get ray casting to work for a 2d game and got to the point where my intsersects are stored correctly in the vector but I can't figure out how to sort the vector correctly, as in if you draw a horizontal line from the player to the left side of the screen and then have create a circle from it
(kinda like in https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/ )

the struct I am using:

```
struct Intersect
{
    bool result = false; Vec2 pos; float angle;
};
```

the attempt to sort it:

```
std::stable_sort(points.begin(), points.end(), [&playerPos](const Intersect& lhs, const Intersect& rhs)
{

    if (playerPos.y < lhs.pos.y)
    {
        if (lhs.pos.x < playerPos.x)
        {
            return  lhs.pos.x < rhs.pos.x;
        }
        else
        {
            return lhs.pos.y > rhs.pos.x;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return lhs.pos.x > rhs.pos.x;
    }
});
```

`playerPos` is a simple `Vec2` with a `x` and `y`.

`points` is the vector of intersects that is filled earlier in the code.

With this attempt I am mostly getting the invalid comparator as it is not strictly weak sorting I think.

Comment: What error message are you getting? Paste the exact, relevant text

Comment: *"...it is not strictly weak sorting I think."* - No thinking about it. Your comparator conditionally flips ordering. I think you may be better off copying out values answering the call to your lead comparison, then sorting each segment individually.

Comment: The error is telling you your comparator doesn't strictly order your elements. See [Comparator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Comment: I think you got the answer. The mechanic is to check each intersection from a line at the left side of the player tracing a circle. Couldn't be an option to sort your elements by the respective angle from that line?

Comment: If Pos = (0,0), A = (1,1) and D = (1, -1), I obtain A >= D and D >= A with your function, therefore A = D. I posted a little program to test this kind of relation, but it is clearly not conformed to the rules here and I was caught by the patrol!

Comment: @Curt Nichols I connected this morning with the intention to suppress the post. It was deleted but it still appears on my window. How can I delete it definitely ?

Comment: I tried sorting it by the angle.. but that list didn't end up good either for some reason...

Comment: You should post the code with selection by the angle